# How disable / remove android activity label and label bar?

Tags: android

Is there anyway to remove activity label bar and label itself which is set by default from application label? 
I'd like to have whole layout from my design and need to remove the label bar and label which is in TOP layout.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the `android:theme` attribute to `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` on your `<activity>` element in your *AndroidManifest.xml* like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: If you want to remove the title bar and app label but keep using a theme (such as `Theme.Holo.Light`) check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10318745/1438809).

Comment: In my case, i assume thats because appcompat and new API levels is : `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Answer (score 22):

If your application theme is AppTheme(or anything else), then in styles.xml add the following code:

```
<style name="HiddenTitleTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
 </style>
```

Then in manifest file add the following in the activity tag for which you want to disable activity label:

```
android:theme="@style/HiddenTitleTheme"
```

Comment: This worked for me because otherwise with,"@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" I got this error" You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.". thank you

Comment: in case someone doesn't know how where to put the styles
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#Styles

Answer (score 12):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

        //set up notitle 
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
        //set up full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,   
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  

        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I am not 100% sure this is what you want but if you are referring to the title bar (the little gray strip at the top), you can remove/customize it via your manifest.xml file...

```
<activity android:name=".activities.Main"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to hide the title bar by hiding it in a specific activity or hiding it on all of the activity in your app.

You can achieve this by create a custom theme in your `styles.xml`.

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

If you are using **AppCompatActivity**, there is a bunch of themes that android provides nowadays. And if you choose a theme that has `.NoActionBar`or `.NoTitleBar`. It will disable you action bar for your theme.

After setting up a custom theme, you might want to use the theme in you activity/activities. Go to manifest and choose the activity that you want to set the theme on.

**SPECIFIC ACTIVITY**

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Notice that I have set the `FirstActivity` theme to the custom theme `MyTheme`. This way the theme will only be affected on certain activity. If you don't want to hide toolbar for all your activity then try this approach.

The second approach is where you set the theme to all of your activity.

**ALL ACTIVITY**

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">

    <activity android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Notice that I have set the application theme to the custom theme MyTheme. This way the theme will only be affected on all of activity. If you want to hide toolbar for all your activity then try this approach instead.

Answer (score 2):

In your project "*res/values/themes*" edit style tag attribute for parent from

```
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
```

to:

```
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```

do this for both *theme.xml* files, it will remove ActionBar and keep default theme.

Comment: This was the problem for me, I used the android studio templates to setup my app and these parents seem to override all of the `windowActionBar` things. Also work noting you need to remove the call to `setupActionBarWithNavController` after doing this

Answer (score 1):

There is a code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289439/android-custom-titlebar-hide-text/4289633#4289633) that does it.

The trick is at this line:

```
 title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: The problem with this solution, as the other post mentions, is that the title bar does show for a brief moment. When I ran into this problem I ended up using the solution that Octavian shows because it's cleaner and you don't run into the temporary title bar issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a drop down menu in the graphical layout window of eclipse. some of the themes in this menu will have ".NoTitleBar" at the end. any of these will do trick.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the others answers was not enough...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> 
</style>

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

Tested on Android 4.0.3 API 15.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I do rake run:android,

my Androidmenifest.xml file is built-up again so my changes done

for NoTitlebar no more persist.

Rather than user adroid_title: 0

This helped me.

edit your build.yml

```
android:
  android_title: 0
  #rest of things 
  #you needed
```

Answer (score 0):

This one.

```
android:theme="@style/android:Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in your activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml to hide label

```
android:label=""
```

Comment: but then the name of the app doesn't show on the home screen among all other apps..

Comment: This was the correct solution for me. Our app theme extends `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` which has `windowNoTitle` set to `true` but still the app_name flashes up briefly on startup. This fix works.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using Android Studio 3+ This will work: android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"

@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar will not support in new API and force you app close.

Answer (score 0):

**First way set the activity theme to NoTitleBar**

```
 android:theme="@style/android:Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

**Second way to ignore it**

```
tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck"
```

Answer (score -1):

with your toolbar you can solve that problem. use setTitle method.

```
 Toolbar   mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  mToolbar.setTitle("");
  setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

super easy :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this only removes the title, not the entire ActionBar. The ActionBar can be completely removed from a specific Activity in the Manifest.

Comment: `getSupportActionBar()?.hide()` would hide the bar if this approach is preferred and you want to do more than remove the text