# how to Remove the space for showing Application name

Tags: android, android-manifest

I developed an application. I would like to remove space that is used
 for showing application name on top of my application UI. (The Title Bar)

I set Application label as null In manifest File But it will not remove the space for showing Application name

Please tell me what is the correct or possible way to do that

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How disable / remove android activity label and label bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388068/how-disable-remove-android-activity-label-and-label-bar)

Comment: Thanks Buddy for the quick replay cheers,Kariyachan

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You request window feature in your onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

or in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".YourClassName"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

Comment: I'd just wanted to add that `requestWindowFeature` should be called before `setContentView`...

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Answer (score 6):

i think you can add this line in you application tag in android manifest file

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

Answer (score 5):

For android studio:

In android AndroidManifest.xml file change the theme like: android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

example

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this style

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/xyz</item>
</style>
```