# How to disable action bar permanently

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I can hide the action bar in honeycomb using this code:

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

But when the keyboard opens, and user copy-pastes anything, the action bar shows again.
How can I disable the action bar permanently?

Comment: Found the answer hhh

    <activity
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    ....
    >

Comment: that not an action bar when you try to copy, paste its default view.

Comment: yes, but after copy paste end, it still there not vanished

Comment: getSupportActionBar().hide();

Answer (score 123, accepted):

By setting activity theme in Manifest,

```
<activity
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
....
>
```

Comment: this seems like the only proper way to do it. esp. if you happen to have a relativelayout at the bottom...

Comment: This is the only way that I can get to work, unfortunately. It removes custom theming, but it is truly the only thing that fully removes the `ActionBar`, for me.

Comment: This doesn't work with the enforcement of AppCompat theme in the new ADT. I don't think fighting this - trying to do away completely from AppCompat is good solution either! I've try @monchote's approach and it works for me

Comment: this should be <activity
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"> 
instead of 

<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

Comment: On Samsung Galaxy J2 it makes the app crash but no problems on Nexus 9

Comment: deprecated using this / not compatible with app compat

Answer (score 264):

If you are using `Theme.Holo.Light` and want to use the `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar` variant on pre 3.2 devices you can add this to your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and then set it as your activity's theme:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" ... />
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Doesn't remove custom theming like @Biji's solution.

Comment: Any idea what the additional flag would be to set hide the notifications bar ?

Comment: I also found it necessary to inherit from FragmentActivity instead of ActionBarActivity.

Comment: @jesses.co.tt The notification bar can be removed using `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>`

Comment: This didn't work for me. Used the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790070/upgraded-to-appcompat-v22-1-0-and-now-getting-illegalargumentexception-appcompa

Answer (score 38):

I use the following code inside my onCreate function:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Source:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: The source seems to be outdated as of 2019. Up to date source: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status

Answer (score 31):

```
<application
    .
    .
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
    . >
```

maybe this help you

Comment: Note that this method requires a mnimum of api level 13

Answer (score 23):

With the Android Studio default generated Activity superclass is `ActionBarActivity` and then, none of solution in other responses works. To solve just change superclass:

```
public class xxxActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
```

to:

```
public class xxxActivity extends Activity {
```

Answer (score 20):

If you want to get full screen without actionBar and Title.

Add it in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

and use the style at manifest.xml.

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 14):

Go to styles.xml
Change this DarkActionBar to **NoActionBar**

```
style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 13):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The best way I found which gives custom themes and no action bar, is to create a SuperClass for all activities in my project and in it's onCreate() call the following line of code -

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

It always work for me. The only issue in this approach is, you'll see action bar for a fraction of second when starting the app (Not the activity, the complete app).

Answer (score 9):

You can force hide the action bar simply:

```
ActionBar  actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
actionbar.hide();
```

Just use your default theme, it will work good if fullscreen is set

Answer (score 6):

Don't use Holo theme and the Actionbar will disappear.
This code is working for me on API 8+, with support lib v7:

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

set that theme for your activity:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" ... />
```

and in your activity class.

It works even when it extends ActionBarActivity.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want a theme with no action bar you can use 'NoActionBar' variant, for eg. if your base theme is as below

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

then you can use

```
<style name="AppThemeNoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

But if you want to retain the properties of your main theme i.e. AppTheme you can do as below

```
<style name="AppThemeNoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

You can retain all the properties of your base theme this way and don't have to explicitly add them in your NoActionBar theme :)

Answer (score 6):

Under *res -> values ->styles.xml*

**Change**

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

To

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

Answer (score 5):

Heres a quick solution.

You find styles.xml and you change the base application theme to "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" as shown below.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Type this code to your `onCreate` method before `setContentView`:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Below are the steps for hiding the action bar permanently:

1. Open app/res/values/styles.xml.
2. Look for the style element that is named "apptheme". Should look
   similar to `<style name="AppTheme"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`.
3. Now replace the parent with any other theme that contains
   "NoActionBar" in its name.

   a. You can also check how a theme looks by switching to the design tab of activity_main.xml and then trying out each theme provided in the theme drop-down list of the UI.
4. If your **MainActivity** extends **AppCompatActivity**, make sure
   you use an AppCompat theme.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to post rather a Designer approach to this, this will keep design separate from your business logic:

Step 1. Create new style in (res->values->styles.xml) : Basically it is copy of your overall scheme with different parent - parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

```
<!-- custom application theme. -->
    <style name="MarkitTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Step 2: In your AndroidManifest.xml, add this theme to the activity you want in: e.g. I want my main activity without action-bar so add this like below:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MarkitTheme">
```

This is the best solution for me after trying a lot of things.

Answer (score 2):

in the onCreate function add the following code

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

and just import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you create a new theme by changing the name of the default theme in the `styles.xml` file to:

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
```

and than change the theme from the drop-down under your `main_activity.xml` to whatever you called your theme.

Answer (score 2):

Use this in `styles.xml` file:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting solution where you want to retain the ViewPager while removing the action bar is to have a style as show

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/NoActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
<style name="NoActionBarStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@null</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
</style>
```

This is the way most of the Dialer applications in android is showing the ViewPager without the action bar.

Ref: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Dialer

Comment: this solution leave a white area in top.

Comment: This worked for me on Android 2.3 with the Theme.AppCompat.Light if I changed the NoActionBarStyle parent to @style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabBar (I'm using a ViewPager)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to disable `ActionBar` in Android.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in your manifist

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution:

in the manifest, inside your activity tag:

```
android:label="@string/empty_string"
```

and in strings.xml:

```
<string name="empty_string">""</string>
```

This way you keep ActionBar (or Toolbar) with the title, but when Activity if created the title is automatically empty.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, none of these worked for me when building on a Nexus 7 running 4.4.2 (API 19).  For the most part, at least with the latest version of Android Studio (1.2.1.1) after creating a blank activity app, the:

> android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

is in the application element, not the activity element.  If I removed the above code or tried to change it to:

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"

the app won't run...if this is happening to you, just go into your styles.xml file (res > values > styles.xml) and add the .NoTitleBar to the end of the parent like this block:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
```

No changes to the AndroidManifest file are needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your `activity_main.xml`, you can adjust from there 
in the line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
.......
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar"
.......    
">
```

Sometimes when you can see things like this [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaBp0.jpg), You can select from here the "noActionBar" theme.

Hope me helped you.

Answer (score -1):

Some answers already been written and if you didn't find `styles.xml` file in `res>values` then you can do this go to `res>values>themes>themes.xml`  here you need to add these two lines inside the style

```
 <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Answer (score -1):

Theme.xml file

```
 <style name="Theme.FurnitureApp.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
```

write the below code before setContent{ } method

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 0)
```