# Close button on top of the activity

Tags: android, button, layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:padding="2dp">

<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="closeActivity"> 
</WebView>
<Button 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/x"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:background="@drawable/close"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" 
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_width="25dp" 
    android:textSize="12sp" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="closeActivity"
     />
```

I want that type of a close button can anyone help me out on top of the layout in the webView.

[Click Here To see the Pic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9e4GvdISertOWtyOEQ4eTJJbEU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: your question is unclear.. and usually we add some relevant code to our questions in Stack OverFlow..

Comment: @MatanDahan Can you help me now .. by Button is not on top of the layout as you see in this link  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9e4GvdISertYUxYMU5iTnZJdlk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It is easy

1. Create a custom dialog.
2. Create a custom layout for that dialog.
3. Design a custom layout using the Relative layout.

Url for the Creation of the Dialog: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: can you reslove my problem better

Answer (score 0):

you might get what you want by removing the ActionBar at the top of the activity..

add this to your activity (which uses the layout you posted here) in AndroidMenifast.xml

```
<activity
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
....
>
```

this code is taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456835/how-to-disable-action-bar-permanently)

tell me if it helps..