# How can I remove the bar?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse, Android 4.0, how can I remove the top bar off my application? I know, we should out it in Manifest .. maybe I want to change the Android 4.0 to Android 2.2 .. but later on.

Comment: add android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen in your manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to hiding the ActionBar that is on top of your application, please take a look at this post: [How to disable action bar permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456835/how-to-disable-action-bar-permanently)