# Android Studio - Action Bar remove

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, manifest

I'm trying to remove/disable the ActionBar. I tried to put in the Manifest:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
</activity>
```

and it doesn't work. It doesn't remove the ActionBar.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>` to your App's theme definition.

Comment: If it didnt help try this too `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Comment: I get an error when I write this:
getSupportActionBar().hide();

Comment: http://prntscr.com/42mpop

Comment: What happens if you try `getActionBar().hide();`???

Comment: Also try this `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar"` instead of `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`

Comment: Nothing. The actionbar is still here

Comment: try the next comment too please..

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion ???

Comment: My minSdkVersion is 7

Comment: okk and target sdk ???

Comment: Try this in your style...`<style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>` and for your <activity> `android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"`

Comment: Doesnt work. I still see the action bar ):

Comment: There is also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456835/how-to-disable-action-bar-permanently

Answer (score 33, accepted):

in your `oncreate()` method use this

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

If your `minSdkVersion` is 10 or lower, instead use:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: When I do that the app crashes on startup

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro I got this too, but changing the theme as shown below worked for me as well. Maybe something changed since this was written.

Answer (score 42):

I had this issue too. I went to `styles.xml` and changed

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

to

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

and that removed it from all my activities.

Comment: Worked. Thanks ! <3

Comment: It worked for me as well. So this is the solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 15):

You can try this. It works for me

Add it in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

and use the style at manifest.xml.

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 6):

For android studio 
You can go to styles.xml and change

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

to

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

and in Eclipse it can be changed in manifest file

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.ExcellenceTech.webview.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Answer (score 5):

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

I think this should work.

Answer (score 3):

You hide action bar by with different ways.

1.action bar hidden through the manifest xml file (non Java Programming), then the easy way is to add the following attribute in Activity tag:

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar"
```

If custom Theme is created then it is convenient to create another style extending the custom theme.

```
 <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
 <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

or

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); OR getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();

getSupportActionBar().hide(); 
  or 
getActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

In AndroidManifest.xml and acitivity section put this code.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

But the change might not appear in the xml design.

Answer (score 1):

Hide Action Bar permanently from styles.xml
If you want to hide Action Bar throughout the app (Activities, Fragments) everywhere, you can simply navigate to res > values > styles.xml and change your Base application theme as mentioned below.

```
 <resources> 
 <! - Base application theme. →
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
 <! - Customize your theme here. →
 <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
 <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
 <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

Hide Action Bar for a particular activity:

Use this in onCreate(); Method

Kotlin:

```
supportActionBar?.hide()
```

Java:

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've found the easiest way by far, if you go to your AndroidManifest.xml file, you'll see `android:theme="@style/Theme.yourappnamehere"`, you can simply replace that with `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`. Tada worked like a dream (no need to add anything)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `hideUi()` function as below and call it in `onCreate()`  method:

```
private void hideUI() {
    // Hide UI first
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
    View mContentView = (findViewById(R.id.mainLayout));
// Delayed removal of status and navigation bar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
        mContentView.getWindowInsetsController().hide(
                WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() | WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars());
    } else {
        // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
        // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
        // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
}
```

call the `hideUI()` in `onCrete()` after `setContentView()` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
    hideUI();
   // ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following codes and work for me:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```