# getSupportActionBar().hide(); is working, but getActionBar().hide(); not

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have tried to hide my `ActionBar`. With the method `getSupportActionBar().hide();` everything works perfectly. My `minSdkVersion` is like I said in this question [Android Studio - Action Bar remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742732/android-studio-action-bar-remove) higher than 11 (mine is 14).

Why is `getActionBar().hide();` not working?

Comment: Why do you use `getActionBar()`?

Comment: What shall I use instead?

Comment: If `getSupportActionBar().hide()` is working, why not use it? The oldest you should consider supporting is 4.4 KitKat (API 19). KitKat and above covers about 95% of Android users.

Comment: Keep using support action bar for all api levels.

Comment: @private Where did you get that number, according to Google it is more like 80%<br> It also makes a difference if you are releasing a new app, or updating an old one. When you are updating an old one, you don't want ton estrange your users. Also, you will keep on getting complaints about old bugs, as old users cannot update.

Comment: @lionscribe you're right, it is more like 80%, but even then, if you have it at API 16 then you get 97% of users. Supporting 14 or even 11 is kind of absurd.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are using the Android Support `Toolbar`, setting it with `setSupportActionBar`, not the built in AppBar. Therefore only `getSupportActionBar` works, and not `getActionBar`, as there is no built in action bar in your app.