# How I can remove the "Status and notification bar"?

Tags: java, android, android-notification-bar

I plan to program an app with Android Studio. But this bar bothers me:

The status and notification bar

[image]

Comment: Add codes which you've tried.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I don't have any code on this topic yet because I haven't found anything

Comment: Do you want to remove the action bar?

Comment: In the picture you can see the bar I mean. So the bar with the time and battery level

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio - Action Bar remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742732/android-studio-action-bar-remove)

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't help

Comment: parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" Change to this in your styles.xml

Comment: I put it in my code, but it's still there. I don't know if the bar I mean is the actionbar

Comment: Share your code. Without code its difficult to help you out.

Comment: The code is too long to insert here. And I don't know if we mean the same thing. Did you look at the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove status bar use this

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

how to use ..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved all problems!

Comment: Glad that i could help you

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to just hide the status bar, it should be just adding this Java code to your activity's onCreate method:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

You can find the Kotlin code here: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status#41

If you are looking to make the app fullscreen with no Android UI you can use this Java code:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}

private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Enables regular immersive mode.
    // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
    // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
            // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            // Hide the nav bar and status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

// Shows the system bars by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
private void showSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

You can find the Kotlin code here: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#EnableFullscreen

All the code snippets are from the Android documentation and not my own.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for! But unfortunately everything is black at this point.
And as soon as I click on the status bar it is back

Comment: Yes, the status bar will come back from hidden state if you tap or swipe on that side. I'm not sure there's a way around that. Also, what do you mean the screen is all black?

Comment: I checked it again. The black one is apparently on my cell phone. Thanks!