# Action bar removal leaves blank space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I'm an android beginner. I did not want my app to have an action bar, so I [disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456835/how-to-disable-action-bar-permanently) it.

However, other views are displayed after a blank padding, which is where the action bar previously was. Like

[image]

How can I have this space removed? I have tried:

- setting the padding of the layout / margin of the views to 0.
- Setting layout_gravity to top

Comment: Use the no action bar theme, as the accepted answer for the question you linked mentioned...

Comment: But it leaves a blank padding. EDIT: Uploaded a screen shot

Comment: Are they all using the correct theme?

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand the question but I'm using android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: Are you sure it's not the image too short? Maybe you could change the background to fit the entire screen even if it should resize the image

Comment: I mean the height of the image is not supposed to equal the height of the screen (the bottom blank space is fine), but I do expect it to stick to the very top (the top blank space is unfine)

Comment: @V0R73X have you tried `getActionBar().hide();`?

Answer (score 5):

Add this code in style.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">0dp</item>
</style>
```

and use this code in Activity theme in manifest.

```
<activity 
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```