# Android Hide Title/Status/Action Bar in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml

I'm working on an Android app where I need to hide the title/status/action bar in an activity. I looked around quite a bit, and tried some things, but none of them worked, just crashed when I ran the app.  I'd prefer to do it through AndroidManifest.xml, rather than programmatically in onCreate(), 'cause I'm not very good with themes and styles and all that.

Comment: Do you want the title/action to be hidden for all activities?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/10318745/4270211

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable action bar permanently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456835/how-to-disable-action-bar-permanently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to edit your AppTheme properly. You find it in `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
  <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

you can then use this as your activitys theme in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: OK, thanks!  That fixed it!  (I also realized I accidentally extended ActionBarActivity in my main Activity, not just Activity.  :/)  Thanks!