# Android design and output not match

Tags: android

I'm new in Android and want to know why my app deisgn isn't same as what i deisgn in Android studio. Here is the image link:
[image: i.stack.imgur.com/7vu1G.png]

1.Why on the top banner will appear "INC AIO" string? Is this related to the layout?How to remove? 
2.Why the login button will locating too close with the password text field, not like my design?

Hope can get help frpm here. Thanks.

Comment: Actually what design you have give over here is big one....and your emulator device is low resolution which one you have selected

Comment: so Select new emulator device which will have high resolution or you need to decrease the size of textView or can you send the xml file ..

Comment: And I think you have written RelativeLayout as parent layout. instead of this take LinearLayout with orientation as vertical...and put all widget (like: edittext ,textview, button) inside Linear layout tag...then it will display as you are expecting ....and for question 1 I have given answer below...

Answer (score 0):

1. This is ActionBar, u can remove it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456835/how-to-disable-action-bar-permanently) is answer how.
2. U need to show us your layout file (.xml)

Answer (score 0):

In **AndroidManifest.xml** you need to add theme inside your activity tag... to remove action bar from top.

just add this code: **android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"**
with no action bar.

**example:**

```
 <activity
                android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" 
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```