# Delete the "Settings" Tab in Navigation drawer

Tags: android, menu, navigation, drawer

I'm developing an app with a Navigation Drawer. But in the top right corner there is always the menue with the tab "Settings". How can I remove that menue as well in the drawer as in the normal view?

Comment: can you post screenshot?

Comment: Just remove that item from a file called menu_main.xml. It is always generated as default when creating a new project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all delete the `main.xml` file under the directory

> "project name"\app\src\main\res\menu

and it should look like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDQpJ.png).

Then, remove a block of code that is in relation to that of the `main.xml` file. It should be located under the MainActivity or the activity where you are seeing the "Settings". Refer to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yzEs.png).

You can also delete the string resource under `strings.xml` file which is named "action_settings" by default.

That is all and your project is clear from what you want to get rid off.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove that item from a file called **menu_main.xml** in menu folder. It is always generated as default when creating a new project in Android Studio.

The xml should look something like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be talking about the action bar, not the navigation drawer. If this is the case, then if you get rid of the `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` methods in your activity, the `Settings` menu item will disappear.

As for the whole action bar, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10318745/3111870) might help.

Answer (score 0):

delete settng menu from the menu_main.xml which indicate in res>menu

Answer (score 0):

Remove the item tag from menu tag, which is present on main.xml, then remove corresponding ID from Activity.java file.