# How to remove the top blue bar in the new original app?

Tags: android

I just started app programming on android studio. I dont want the top blue bar you get automatically in the top of every app you create. how do i remove it? sorry if stupid question.

Comment: Toolbar or Status Bar? BTW I give you the clue on what to search ;)

Comment: hint : change the theme to NoActionBar

Comment: Thanks that did the job :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable action bar permanently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456835/how-to-disable-action-bar-permanently)