# How to remove an extra line under toolbar? (android)

Tags: android, android-toolbar

[image]
in my xml i have only listview and toolbar, i dont uderstand why after emulating i see an extra blue line under the toolbar

```
  android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    />


    <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />
```

Thank you

Comment: look into android:fitsSystemWindows

Comment: i have: android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

Comment: try setting it to "false"

Answer (score 1):

Change your styles.xml and AndroidManifest.xml to remove action bar and title

styles.xml:

```
<style name="NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and then set it as your activity's theme in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" ... />
```

Refer [How to disable action bar permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456835/how-to-disable-action-bar-permanently)

Answer (score 0):

Your app's theme should extends some "NoActionBar" theme, for example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- your app configuration here -->
</style>
```