# remove top bar Android app

Tags: android

How can I remove top bar that says Project 1.

[image]

Comment: change the style of your app in the Androidmanifest file. Look for a style without an action bar

Comment: Have you tried [No action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456835/how-to-disable-action-bar-permanently) ?

Answer (score 5):

Try this first define style in stlye.xml

```
 //NoActionBar

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Than in mainfest file declare class style as below

```
    <activity
        android:name="youractivityName"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `new NavigationPage (new YourPage())` in the App class make sure to change it to `new YourPage()`. or if you are if you are getting to the page when an event is fired don't use it like this `Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage ( new YourPage())`. instead use `Navigation.PushAsync( new YourPage())`

Comment: Or alternatively you can go to the XAML for  the page in the first heading of your content page and set the  NavigationPage.HasTitleBar to false.