# android, how to disable only activity name from menu bar

Tags: android, android-activity, menu

I know this has been answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388068/how-disable-remove-android-activity-label-and-label-bar)

But I just want to stop displaying the activity name, but still continue to  display the menu items as in the following pic where I don't want to see "Schedule" in activity bar.

[image]

Comment: are you talking about the actionbar http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html ?

Comment: yes, action bar, added the pic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [disable the title](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowTitleEnabled%28boolean%29):

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Using ActionbarSherlock:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I have MinSDK as 8, and it is not supported to setDisplayShowTitleEnabled. Adding @SupressLint is crashing the app.

Comment: you need to get ActionbarSherlock if you want the ActionBar pre ice cream sandwitch http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can add something like `getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` to the `onCreate` method of your `Activity`.