# Android: Remove title from activity

Tags: android

I've added this code to onCreate in each of my activites.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

However, when running on my phone, there's a brief moment on loading the app where it can be seen.  Is there a way to remove it altogether?  I don't want the title bar on any of my activites.

Comment: add this code in      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" application tag in your manifest file...

Answer (score 2):

put this line in style.xml file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>
```

It will gives the new api features looks and feel and if you change the style like

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar
```

then it gives the lower version api look and feel

Answer (score 2):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

should be used before `setContentView();`

**EDIT**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

        //set up notitle 
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
        //set up full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,   
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  

        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
}
```

Comment: It is, it's the first thing I do in the onCreate method.

Answer (score 1):

You can define theme attribute into application tag in manifest

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" ...
```

or can use style as

```
<style name="generalnotitle" parent="general">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Read more at : -

[How to hide the title bar for an Activity in XML with existing custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)

[How disable / remove android activity label and label bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388068/how-disable-remove-android-activity-label-and-label-bar)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

Answer (score 0):

in your AndroidManifest.xml modify your activity like this.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.test.Second"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to drop the title bar for all your activities you can change the android:theme attribute in the application tag of your manifest file as in:

```
<application
   android:icon="@drawable/icon"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show Title bar in your whole application then you can change your base theme of your application in `style.xml` from project res and inside `values` directory.

For me it default comes like

`<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">`

and I change it to

`<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">`

and it works for me. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest file just paste this inside the activity tags

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            />
```