# Application name in home screen of the phone needed but no main activity title

Tags: android

I would like to have no title of the Main Activity visible. And at the same time I would like to have in my Home Screen of the phone the application icon with the application name visible. Currently I cannot remove main activity title without removing application name in my Home Screen of the phone.

**To be more precise I need a title bar** in the Main Activity (so I cannot use @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" option). In the title bar I have settings (and it is comfortable to use it there). I would like to remove only the text name.

This is a code in my Android Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <activity
       android:name="org.app.MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/no_title" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

And the code in strings.xml:

```
<string name="app_name">App Name</string>
<string name="no_title"></string>
```

Removing line: android:label="@string/no_title", did not work and “App Name” is visible in a title bar of my Main Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting Theme.NoTitleBar to your application.

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Source: [How disable / remove android activity label and label bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388068/how-disable-remove-android-activity-label-and-label-bar)

Comment: Hello, I cannot remove a title bar completely because in the title bar of my main activity I have settings to the application. I would like to remove just a name itself.

Comment: Try - getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.no_title); in your onCreate method of the Activity.

Comment: This getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.no_title); removes also the name of the application in my Home Screen of the phone (I see only an icon and I need a name too)

Comment: try, getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled (false); I am just giving all the possibilities we can try here. :)

Comment: Hmm this almost work :)
Why almost? Becase on activity start I see the title (~0.5 sec) and it disappears. Do you have any more ideas? :)

Comment: I found the soultion! BOTH  getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled (false); (thank you @Atul O Holic) AND removing android:label="@string/no_title" from the code above! :):):)

Comment: Great :) Would you mind sharing it? and accepting the answer if it helped :)

Comment: I found the soultion! BOTH getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled (false); (thank you @Atul O Holic) AND removing android:label="@string/no_title" from the code above! :):):)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47869/discussion-between-atul-o-holic-and-annabelle)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your activity in your manifest.xml

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

or you can also set it fullscreen by adding this

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

**EDIT**
or in your case:

```
<activity
       <android:name="org.app.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/no_title" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

Comment: Please read my additional comments above. I need a title bar. I just would like to remove a text title

Comment: @Annabelle maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android