# Don't want to show label and settings menu on my main screen

Tags: android

I wanted to show first screen (user's registration) without label and settings menu.

would someone please suggest me how?

### Following is the code from manifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How disable / remove android activity label and label bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388068/how-disable-remove-android-activity-label-and-label-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings icon is the `menu` option in Android. To remove that just remove the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method. But since you also want to remove the title, all in all what you are asking is to remove the action bar itself. That means you want a full screen activity and for that you can simply set a style in the android manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```