# What is this action bar, and where can I find it to modify it?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am modifying an three year ago app from my company.
As you see on picture, there is a very ugly gray thin action bar on the top.
I want to modify it, but I couldn't find it anywhere in the packages.
This is an API 14 Android 4.0 app.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, it is title bar.

Comment: It's a title bar. You can update your styles file to latest action bar styles to include an action bar in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the style of the app (or activity) with something like:

```
@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar
```

You can find more here:
[How disable / remove android activity label and label bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388068/how-disable-remove-android-activity-label-and-label-bar)

And create your own layout or use the action bar. If you just want to change the text, change the label